# Scala SeqLike distinct preserves order?

Tags: scala

The apidoc of `distinct` in `SeqLike` says:

*Builds a new sequence from this sequence without any duplicate elements.
  Returns: A new sequence which contains the first occurrence of every element of this sequence.*

Do I feel it correct that no ordering guarantee is provided? More generally, do methods of SeqLike provide any process-in-order (and return-in-order) guarantee?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On the contrary: operations on `Seq`s guarantee the output order (unless the API says otherwise). This is one of the basic properties of sequences, where the order matters, versus sets, where only containment matters.

Comment: So SeqLike doesn't have to guarante but Seq has?

Comment: I don't think this is technically correct. While sequences obviously have order I couldn't find anything that would mention preserving it on every operation. I agree that some people would expect this, but I don't think an implementation that puts sequence items into a `Set` and returns them in any order would violate any contract. Having said that I believe current implementation preserves order.

Comment: @pazabo You're probably right that there is no strong guarantee—neither from a specification, nor, of course from any tool, compiler, linter, etc., but anyone going against this principle can easily be accused of violating the principle of least surprise, and the standard lib doesn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the collection you were using in the first place. If you had a list you'll get your order. If on the other hand you had a set, then probably not.

Comment: A set isn't SeqLike, though and the OP's stated the collection referred to is SeqLike

Comment: Yeah, I guess my answer is more general... I should have expressed myself more clearly.